# Winmerge as RTC Compare Editor

Tags: rtc, winmerge, rational-team-concert

Can some one help me how to configure WinMerge as RTC's compare editor?

My friend used BeyondCompare however I am more comfortable with WinMerge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/47177/code-comparison-tool-with-rtc) does mention:

> I've always used WinMerge. Beyond Compare is also a good compare tool but it's not free.
>
> You can configure RTC to use another compare tool in `Windows > Preferences > Team > Jazz Source Control > External Compare Tool`.
> There are defaults configurations for both the tools listed above or you can enter a path for you own compare tool.

See more at "[Can I use any other diff/merge tool, other than the one provided in RTC?](https://jazz.net/library/article/601)"

[image: https://jazz.net/library/content/articles/rtc/3.0/faq-rtc-visual-studio/images/compare_tool_configuration.png]
<sup>(the picture shows "BeyondCompare", but there should be WinMerge as well in the dropdown list)</sup>

> We have pre-configured some popularly used compare/merge tools like Beyond Compare, DiffMerge, P4Merge and **WinMerge**.

Comment: @DeepakVasudevan Sure: don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Yes. I accepted the answer and voted it up too. Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: @DeepakVasudevan Thank oyu: you can review your past questions as well: those which are answered to your satisfaction should have an accepted answer.